Underscore operator combined with "in"
Hello I am trying to learn Swift and am struggling with the _ operator. I somewhat understand it's used to discard a result of a return value, but I am not sure what it means when combined with other things, considering this code:
init<V: Hashable>(tag: V, selection: Binding<V?>, label: String = "")
{
    self._isSelected = Binding(
        get: { selection.wrappedValue == tag },
        set: { _ in selection.wrappedValue = tag}
    )
    
    self.label = label
}

And the specific line:
set: { _ in selection.wrappedValue = tag}

Is very confusing to me. I am really unsure as to what is being executed here as I have not dealt with "in" other than when trying to loop.
I also am new to programming and my vocabulary is not strong and I am not sure what the type of the "in" command is. I don't think it's an operator.. but am unsure what to call it.
I have tried searching google to explain, but since my vocab is so terrible I am not even sure how to lookup the specific definition of the "in" command.
This is a code snip from a radio button feature and I am trying to determine where the code is to set the selection to unselected.

I'm going to close this now as duplicate, since there's a very good overview of all of this. It's a good question and sometimes tricky to search for, but it has an existing answer. You can ping me here if you believe there's more to your question that isn't answered there and we can reopen this.

There are various ways underscores are used. In your particular case, you have a closure and the <something> in part says "this closure is going to be passed a parameter. Inside the body of the closure, name that parameter <something>. If you say _ in you are telling the compiler "I know the closure takes a parameter, and I am not using that parameter. I don't care. The underscore says "don't assign the parameter to any local variable. I don't need it."
